# How to prevent going to the Specs folder when the page URL changes during the test

Tags: cypress

I use Cypress to automate routine checks.

In general, there is a problem that I cannot find a solution to. There is a small test that checks the presence of the word "Electronic" on the page.

```
it.("Название", () => {
cy.visit("someUrl");
cy.getEl("field-login").type(v.operrtest);
cy.getEl("field-password").type(v.operrtestpass);
cy.getEl("button-save").click();
cy.getEl("field-name-docSeries").type(v.validPassSer);
cy.wait(500);
cy.getEl("field-name-docNumber").type(v.validPassNum);
cy.contains("Найти").click();
cy.get(".preloader-container").should("not.exist");
cy.wait(2000);
//---Переход на новый фронт---
cy.contains("Перейти на новую версию").click();
//---ввод реквизитов---
cy.getEl("overflow-menu-button-overflow-menu-button").click();
cy.contains("Выпустить дебетовую карту").click();
cy.contains("Запуск процесса").should("not.exist");
cy.pause();
cy.getEl("tariffPlan").type(v.tariffname).type("{enter}");
cy.getEl("cardTypepersonal").click();
cy.getEl("personalCardPaySystem")
.type(v.personalCardPaySystem)
.type("{enter}");
cy.getEl("personalCardCategory")
.type(v.personalCardCategory)
.type("{enter}");
cy.getEl("buttonComplete").click();
//---ЭФ корзины---
cy.contains("Единое заявление");
cy.getEl("button-goForward").click();
//---ЭФ печать---
cy.contains("Электронный");
});
```

The problem occurs after we get to the line `cy.contains("Запуск процесса").should("not.exist");`

Here we are waiting for the preloader to load, after which we get to a new URL and a form opens with the inputs, which we fill out next. But after the above line is processed, we are simply thrown into the Specs folder in the Cypress interface.

I have no idea how to fix this, maybe someone has encountered this problem, I ask for help.